# How to rename section in onenote using onenote api

Tags: office365, onenote

I am trying to rename section name using onenote API.
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks/{my notebook id}/sections

- The notebook has the renamed section.
  Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you add more details? Thanks!

Comment: we used graph api for creating notebooks,sections,pages. now we are trying to rename the notebooks,sections. 

Please suggest me PATCH request url.

Comment: Please suggest any PHP onenote SDK url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/code-samples-and-sdks which has PHP SDK and sample code like
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/blob/dev/tests/Functional/OnenoteTest.php

Using Microsoft Graph APIs, you can do PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/sections/{id} and give {"displayName":"new SectionName"}

Comment: I want to rename notebook name. i tried below Graph request.


PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{id}

                                   
I am getting "UnknownError",  Please suggest PATCH Request url to rename notebook.

Comment: How to delete notebook using onenote API, please suggest DELETE request url

Answer (score 1):

To rename a notebook is similar to rename a section. PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/{id} and give {"displayName":"new NotebookName"}

To delete a notebook, use the same url as above with the DELETE action

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried to rename notebook below error is coming.


Client error: `PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/1-6a5bbbff-2d7c-4d6f-99b6-50005f10a176` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{
"error": {
"code": "UnknownError",
"message": "{\r\n \"Message\": \"No HTTP resource was found that matc (truncated...)

Comment: Can you share the client request id response header value and the time you made the request? Thanks!

Comment: I used Microsoft Graph  library , the flowing php code is my request code.

  $section_name1 = "new note name";
  $section_name = '{"displayName":"'.$section_name1.'"}';
  $objective_group_section = $graph->createRequest("PATCH", "/me/onenote/notebooks/1-6a5bbbff-2d7c-4d6f-99b6-50005f10a176")
           ->addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))
           ->attachBody($section_name)
           ->setReturnType(Model\Notebook::class)
           ->execute();

Comment: please share any example code to delete and rename notebook Thanks!

Comment: client request id : c934490c-97c5-44aa-917f-f38470b526d4

Comment: response header:>addHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "application/json"))

Comment: time I made the request : 10:00 PM IST

Comment: i my issue is solved  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105157/how-to-delete-and-rename-notebook-name-using-onenote-graph-api/50158384?noredirect=1#comment87494817_50158384 thank you for you support